# Is it possible to preload data by default, to the target database from MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

**There are certain tables, that does not often change:**

- Country (ID / Name / Abbreviations)
- IPs by Countries (ID / IP Range)

During the development, every time I modify something on the database I have to preload these tables manually into the newly created database.

Is there any way to query these datas automatically to the tables at every `Forward Engineer` process in MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each table in a MySQL Workbench model file has a section called "Inserts". Open a table in the table editor and click the tab labeled "Inserts". There you can add as many records as you wish and this data is applied when you forward engineer your model.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply create a import/export script with the tables you want or even the whole database. e.g.:

```
mysqldump -hHOST_FROM -u -p database_name table_name --no-create-db --no-create-info mydb | mysql -hHOST_TO -u -p database_name
```

BTW: "I choose a lazy person to do a hard job. Because a lazy person will find an easy way to do it" - Bill Gates.

Comment: I am doing the same right now, I was wondering if there is any way to make Workbench do this for me.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You can still save this script as I've said before and whenever you need run it (including on Workbench). Don't get to attached to an IDE.